# How to concatenate appropriate 2 elements from two different for each loops in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, concatenation

I have the following XML-code and I'm trying to concatenate every **keyword** with it's **gnd_id**, but don't how to implement "for each" and "concatenate" together.

**The output should be:Test, 4354672-9; Test1, 4023299-2**

It's my XML:

```
<_nested__objekttyp__schlagworte>
      <objekttyp__schlagworte>
        <_id>3146</_id>
        <lk>
          <schlagworte date-created="2016-05-03T16:47:48+02:00" date-last-updated="2016-05-03T22:50:15+02:00">
            <_id>23</_id>
            <keyword>
              <de-DE>Test</de-DE>
            </keyword>
            <gnd_id>4354672-9</gnd_id>
          </schlagworte>
        </lk>
      </objekttyp__schlagworte>
      <objekttyp__schlagworte>
        <_id>3147</_id>
        <lk>
          <schlagworte date-created="2016-05-03T17:11:58+02:00" date-last-updated="2016-05-03T22:45:38+02:00">
            <_id>24</_id>
            <keyword>
              <de-DE>Test1</de-DE>
            </keyword>
            <gnd_id>4023299-2</gnd_id>
          </schlagworte>
        </lk>
      </objekttyp__schlagworte>
```

and this is my XSLT:

```
<subject>                                             
        <xsl:for-each select="objekttyp/_nested__objekttyp__schlagworte/objekttyp__schlagworte/lk/schlagworte/schlagwort">
        <xsl:value-of select="de-DE"/>

        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="objekttyp/_nested__objekttyp__schlagworte/objekttyp__schlagworte/lk/schlagworte">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1">, </xsl:if>
         <xsl:value-of select="gnd_id"/>
        </xsl:for-each> 

        </subject>
```

Comment: Well, processing `<xsl:for-each select="objekttyp/_nested__objekttyp__schlagworte/objekttyp__schlagworte/lk/schlagworte"><xsl:value-of select="concat(keyword/de-DE, ', ', gnd_id)"/></xsl:for-each>` seems to be easy to achieve based on the code you have already posted.

Comment: If you want a text output, why is there a `subject` element in your stylesheet?

Comment: @MartinHonnen     perfect, thank you, it works. didn't think about that to find decision only with one loop

Comment: @michael.hor257k subject is a dublin core tag and my text output should be in this tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/_nested__objekttyp__schlagworte">
    <xsl:for-each select="objekttyp__schlagworte/lk/schlagworte">
        <xsl:value-of select="keyword/de-DE" />
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="gnd_id" />
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text>; </xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There is no real reason to use concatenation here; you can simply place the individual values directly into the output tree.